# Silence Conda Shell Warning

Tags: python, bash, conda

When I activate a Conda environment in a Bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
conda activate ./myenv
which python
python do_stuff.py
```

The activate line prints out the long warning:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

How do I silence this warning? If I run the `conda init bash` command it suggests, that causes Conda to activate my environment by default for all Bash shells, which is definitely not what I want. That's the default configuration in Conda and I explicitly turned that off after it broke functionality everywhere across my system. I want Conda to function similar to virtualenv, where I have a folder containing the environment, and activate it only when needed for a specific application. Under no circumstances do I want a Conda environment activated for every instance of Bash run anywhere on my system.

I'm not sure why it's giving me a CommandNotFoundError, because otherwise Conda populates my Bash shell with the correct paths to Python and other environment-specific resources, and everything else works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend the following code in your script.

```sh
eval "$(command conda 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
```

This initialize the conda in the script only.

Comment: This did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialize `conda` it will auto activate the base environment on every new shell session you open, by default. If you would like to turn this behavior off, just run once:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```